# Does "ctm for ZFC" (or some other subtheory ZF, ZF-P...) mean we only have finitely many axioms of that theory in our model?

Tags: set-theory

I am working my way through Kunen's Set Theory and I am struggling to grasp what exactly is going on. I have heard it mentioned that ctm's of ZFC are not actually models of ZFC, but of finitely many axioms of ZFC (since Comprehension and Replacement are schemata). But sometimes we prove Replacement or Comprehension for ctm's (or maybe we never do this, and I am just misremembering, can't really find an example now), and it doesn't seem like we're proving a finite number of instances of Replacement or Comprehension.

Here's what I think is going on (but I would not be surprised if I was very wrong):

Sometimes these are models of finitely many ZFC axioms and sometimes we actually mean models of full-blown ZFC and I am missing the cues that indicate which of the two we're talking about (the latter ones cannot be proven to exist in ZFC, since that would violate the Incompletness theorems, so each time we're working with one, we are assuming its existence).

Thank you very much in advance for any input!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when Kunen starts a theorem with "Let $M$ be a ctm for ZF..." he means a ctm for the full ZF assuming one exists.  If he meant a ctm for a finite subset of ZF he'd be more precise in stating what finite subset discussed earlier in the book the theorem is referring to.

Comment: You are most likely correct, I am just confused about the comments I've heard in the lecture, and also seen in Kunen (page 145: "It turns out to be sufficient that we can produce a ctm for any desired finite subset of ZFC by using the Reflection Theorem."), but maybe it will be clearer for me later on. Many thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The naive version of what Kunen does is as follows. We work in ZFC, and we suppose there is a transitive model $M$ of ZFC. We then do various things to produce a transitive model $M'$ of ZFC + $\neg$CH, for instance. So we have proved that ZFC proves that if ZFC has a transitive model, then there is a transitive model of ZFC where the continuum hypothesis fails. However, this doesn't actually tell us that ZFC is equiconsistent with $\neg$CH; in particular, it's consistent with ZFC that ZFC has a model, but not a transitive model (this follows from the incompleteness theorem).

The subtle, more complicated version is this. Consider a finite subset $Q$ of the axioms of ZFC. We then produce a finite subset $Q'$ of the axioms of ZFC. Then, working in ZFC, we show that if there is a transitive model of $Q'$, then there is a transitive model of $Q + \neg$CH. Finally, we appeal to the reflection theorem to produce a model of $Q'$. Therefore, we have shown that for all finite subsets $Q$ of ZFC, ZFC proves there is a transitive model of $Q + \neg$CH.

Now suppose ZFC + $\neg$CH is inconsistent. Then take some finite subset $Q$ of ZFC such that $Q + \neg$CH is inconsistent. Then ZFC proves that $Q + \neg$CH is inconsistent. ZFC also proves that $Q + \neg$CH has a model. Therefore, ZFC is inconsistent.