# Understanding relative consistency in Kunen

Tags: set-theory

I am trying to wrap my head around the following theorem in Kunen's Set theory:
$$\text{Con}(ZF)\implies \text{Con}(ZFC+V=L) \text{ and }
 \text{Con}(ZF)\implies \text{Con}(ZFC+GCH)$$
Now he says that this follows from what we've just proven. But we proved that if $V=L$ holds, then we have the Axiom of Choice (in fact a strong form of AC), and if we have $V=L$ we also have $GCH$. So I don't really understand how this translates into these implications of the consistencies.

Many thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: You got an explanation of this in a [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4835637) answer.  $\bigcup_\alpha L_\alpha$ is a proper-class model of $ZFC+(V=L)+GCH$.  If there is proof of a contradiction from $ZFC+(V=L)$ or $ZFC+GCH$, it only uses a finite fragment of $ZF$.  By transitioning to set-sized models of finite fragments you arrive at a contradiction in $ZF$.

Comment: @ChadK That just goes to show that I'm not really grasping what's going on... Thanks for the comment! I'll think about this for a bit!

Comment: See corollary I.16.14 in Kunen.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Exactly what I was looking for! If you write it as a comment I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The significance of the preceding theorems that $\sf V=L\to AC\land GCH$ is just that you can move from $\sf Con(ZF) \to Con(ZF + V=L)$ to the much more exciting  $\sf Con(ZF) \to Con(ZFC + GCH)$ (i.e. the landmark result that Godel invented the constructible universe to prove). It doesn't have anything to do with why $\sf Con(ZF) \to Con(ZF + V=L).$

The latter holds by combining the result that for every axiom $\varphi$ of $\sf ZF + V=L,$ we have $\sf ZF \vdash \varphi^L$ (by II.6.11 and II.6.13) with the metamathematical result I.16.14 from the previous chapter. The idea of I.16.14 is simple: if there were a proof of contradiction from $\sf ZF+V-L$, then within $\sf ZF,$ we could prove $\varphi^L$ each of the finitely many axioms $\varphi$ of $\sf ZF + V=L$ used in the proof, then carry out the exact same proof of a contradiction (just with every statement relativized to $L$). And thus $\sf ZF$ would be inconsistent.